# subform display not updating (but its record count can be seen to be changing in vba)

Tags: ms-access

I've tried more than half-a-dozen distinct configurations, without success. The first, and simplest, way that I tried:

Main form with two unbound sub-forms; left-hand sub-form is for selecting a "category"; right-hand sub-form is intended to list all "items" within the selected category for the current record of the main form. In the "current" handler of the category sub-form, I set the recordsource of the "items" sub-form to a string of dynamic SQL that basically says

```
"SELECT x, y, z, FROM tblItems WHERE itemCategory = " & selectedCategory & " AND itemOwner = " & parentRecordId
```

The "items" sub-form should display the selected x, y, z values in a continuous datasheet.

Stepping through with debugger, I can see that the record count of the "items" sub-form changes to the expected numbers as I select different categories, but the displayed results never change (in many of the ways I've tried, the entire tblItems is displayed).

I have lots of details I can provide on this and the many variations I've tried, but thinking best(?) to keep this initial post short.

Comment: Is the subform linked to the parent form?

Comment: Comments don't generate emails? I checked back for the first 24 hours or so, then moved on. I feel badly for not having responded to these sooner. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: In my 1st attempt, both subforms were unbound. I did try a version in which I linked the 2nd subform to the main form, and then just changed the recordsource to update the selected category; I also tried pushing the selected category value to a control on the main form so I could link the 2nd subform completely without any need to change its recordsource... neither approach (nor several others) worked.

Comment: (Un)fortunately, what worked in the end is the old "tincture of time" cure... I left it for a few days and tried again from scratch, with success. But I gained no insight into the problem; my fresh attempt was the same (as far as I could tell) as my 1st attempt. Obviously not, but I could not determine (using diff tools) any functional differences between the working and not-working versions. Sigh.

Answer (score 0):

I take it that you have forced a refresh of the data source using a form.refresh or form.recalc method?

Comment: Yes, at the time, I certainly tried adding .Requery and .Refresh statements after changing the recordsource, though the requery seemed unnecessary (as the record count was changing in a way that told me the new recordsource query was working) and the refresh had no effect. As I note in comments above, I now have it working but have no clear idea what was wrong before, which is frustrating.

Comment: Glad you got it working.  If you feel like posting your original (non-working) code or db, then perhaps we can help debug better.